# Подключение к собственному серверу

Tags: http

Я написал небольшой `http-сервер` на `c++` с портом `5555`. Если подключаться к нему с той же машины через `127.0.0.1:5555`, то он принимает подключение и высылает ответ. Если же подключаться через ip-адрес машины, то доступ к серверу получить не удается. Никакой `Firewall` или подобное на машине не стоит.

Comment: Покажите как Вы делаете bind - скорее всего вы биндитесь на локалхост.

Answer (score 0):

Уже исправил) Запускаю сервер на 0.0.0.0)